# Combination of Boolean-based and Time-dependent SQL injection in sqlmap

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, sqlmap

I came across a Blind SQL injection vulnerability which is Boolean-based but the response I get from the server is time-based. In other words if the condition is "false" website returns "error" statement.. if the condition is "true" the page does NOT load.

For example

> http://testingzone.com/id=123+OR+1=2

returns "Error Invalid ID"

> http://testingzone.com/id=123+OR+1=1

returns nothing and the page keeps loading forever (I tested it for 60s with no response and also I didn't receive time-out error from the browser)

I am able to perform attack manually but I am interested in knowing how to perform such attack in sqlmap.

sqlmap failed to identify that it's injectable but it shows several "request timeout errors". How can I tell sqlmap that when request times out means the condition is true?

[UPDATE]

I am kinda started forming an image about why it takes so long time to respond... When I add `LIMIT 1` to query I get the error although I am using `OR 1=1` but when I set it to `LIMIT 1000000` I get no response and page keeps loading (because it takes so much time executing the query)

In other words, it always shows the error but the query execution time indicates whether the query has been successfully executed or not.

Comment: Try `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: @Gumbo I will never return "true" because the other conditions in the query are assumed to be always "false"

Comment: Then find a case where all other conditions are also true.

Comment: @Gumbo even if I managed to do this, how this is supposed to help sqlmap?

Comment: Provide sqlmap a request that returns records and it can work with it.

Comment: @Gumbo As I mentioned, the issue is that the page does not return results when the request is true... It remains loading till request times out. However, if it's false it returns an error

Comment: Does it also for just `id=123`?

Comment: No, it just returns the result (it's a file actually)

Comment: And `id=123 AND 1=1` returns an error?

Comment: @Gumbo Yes. It returns invalid id error

Comment: I am kinda started forming an image about why it takes so long time to respond... When I add `LIMIT 1` to query I get the error although I am using `OR 1=1` but when I set it to `LIMIT 1000000` I get no response and page keeps loading (because it takes so much time executing the query)

Comment: Can’t you provide a valid ID?

Comment: @Gumbo I do provide valid IDs and I am able to get results when I don't add additional queries but for some reason I haven't figured out yet (it probably checks that parameter is numeric before printing result) when I add anything else it executes query but shows an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to automate it. I can simply make it time-based sql injection by adding a condition like 
    OR 1=SLEEP(5) LIMIT 1
In this case it will still print the error but website will take 5 seconds to respond. 
[UPDATE]I managed to apply attack vector in sqlmap using the following command

> python sqlmap.py -u "http://testingzone.com/page.php?id=1*" --suffix "LIMIT 1 --" --dbms "mysql" --cookies "website cookies"

And sqlmap managed to identify that it's time-based sql injection vulnerable url